# optimize a select create with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

i'm in the middle of a war with a select that attacks a view(really big view). my problem is that i want to reduce the reponse time, cos i can go to the toilet, coming back and make a sandwich. I hope apologize my bad sense of humor. So this is the famous select:

```
if (periodeDeute != null && clauDeute != null) {
            if (periodeDeute.equals(EPeriodeDeute.EXECUTIVA)) {// EXEC

                sql.append("SELECT VGPT_EXE.*, VGPT_EXE_E.* FROM ")
                        .append(Constants.T_VW_GPT_E_BASIC)
                        .append(" VGPT_EXE, ")
                        .append(Constants.T_VW_GPT_E_EXTES)
                        .append(" VGPT_EXE_E ")
                        /* filtre */
                        .append("WHERE VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY + "= ").append("VGPT_EXE_E.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY).append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_EXE_E.").append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_PERIODE + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_EXE_E.").append(Constants.CC_PERIODE)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_EXE_E.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_EXE_E.").append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_EXE_E.").append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_PERIODE + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_EXE.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV + "= ? ");
            }
            if (periodeDeute.equals(EPeriodeDeute.VOLUNTARIA)) {// VOL
                sql.append("SELECT VGPT_VOL.*, VGPT_VOL_E.* FROM ")
                        .append(Constants.T_VW_GPT_V_BASIC)
                        .append(" VGPT_VOL, ")
                        .append(Constants.T_VW_GPT_V_EXTES)
                        .append(" VGPT_VOL_E ")
                        /* filtre */
                        .append("WHERE VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY + "= ").append("VGPT_VOL_E.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY).append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_VOL_E.").append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_PERIODE + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_VOL_E.").append(Constants.CC_PERIODE)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_VOL_E.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_VOL_E.").append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV + "= ")
                        .append("VGPT_VOL_E.").append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV)
                        .append(" AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_ANY + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_NUM_REBUT + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_PERIODE + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_CONCEPTE + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_EMISOR + "= ? ")
                        .append("AND VGPT_VOL.")
                        .append(Constants.CC_COD_PROV + "= ? ");
            }
            try {

                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOG.debug("SQL> " + sql.toString());
                }

                try {
                    llista = jdbcTemplate.query(
                            sql.toString(),
                            new Object[] { clauDeute.getCcAny(),
                                    clauDeute.getCcNumRebut(),
                                    clauDeute.getCcPeriode(),
                                    clauDeute.getCodConcepte(),
                                    clauDeute.getCodEmissor(),
                                    clauDeute.getCodProveidor() },
                            new MapperDeuteDetall());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
                if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
                    LOG.error("No es pot recuperar la llista de deutes bàsics",
                            ex);
                }
                throw new GptException(
                        "No es pot recuperar la llista de deutes", ex);
            }
        }
```

just the select:

```
SELECT VGPT_EXE.*
     , VGPT_EXE_E.*
  FROM vw_gpt_e_basic VGPT_EXE
     , vw_gpt_e_extes VGPT_EXE_E
 WHERE VGPT_EXE.cc_any          = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_any
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_num_rebut    = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_num_rebut
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_periode      = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_periode
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_concepte = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_cod_concepte 
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_emisor   = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_cod_emisor
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_prov     = VGPT_EXE_E.cc_cod_prov
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_any          = 1994
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_num_rebut    = 201
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_periode      = 1
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_concepte = 500
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_emisor   = 004
   AND VGPT_EXE.cc_cod_prov     = 43
     ;
```

it's not really hard select, but it's terrible slow. it has a lot of registers and it's created by too many tables, is there anyway to do it faster? with java or whatever.

ty.

Comment: Can you find out the cost of the same query with just using select * and using select 'column1', 'column2' etc?

Comment: do you need all columns of VGTP_EXE and VGPT_EXE_E ? if not only select does columns instead of all (*)!

Comment: I need all the columns, i try without * ty for answering.

Comment: You need an index for the columns in the WHERE clause.  Confirm it with EXPLAIN PLAN.  If there's a TABLE SCAN, that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by not creating those query strings over and over again.  Make them `static final`.

But that's not your solution.

The problem is your query.  Here are some things you can do to try to speed it up:

1. Run EXPLAIN PLAN and look for table scans.
2. Add indexes to columns in WHERE clauses.
3. Reorder the WHERE clauses so the ones that eliminate the most rows appear first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you underling database, some databases have good algorithms for customizing the where clause to minimize the returned rows as soon as possible.
If you are not using these databases our, your database does not have much intelligence, re order the where clauses

So if, for example `VGPT_EXE.cc_periode      = 1` makes lots of rows out of select put it first. You need to analyze the data in your table to find out best order.

Answer (score 1):

This query can create issues.

1. Query Compiler can take a lot of time if there are a lot of columns in your table.
2. Selecting all columns will definitely reduce your chances of using a covering index.
3. There can be TEMPTABLE transactions ( I am not entirely sure about this) which might affect.

Suggest you look at the explain plans, query cost and try tuning query as per your original requirements.